# CAST(hex_num AS DateTime) - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, datetime

When exporting data (rclick db | Tasks | Generate scripts ... ) datetime columns get exported in this way:

```
CAST(0xFFFF2E4600000000 AS DateTime)
```

On

```
select CAST(0xFFFF2E4600000000 AS DateTime)
```

..in SQL Server Mgmt Studio I get:

```
1753-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I need this (i.e. 0xFFFF2E4600000000 here) converted to regular date-time in another program.

Now, I know how the format works for dates later than Jan 1 1900:

```
first 4 bytes == the days since 1st Jan 1900
2nd 4 bytes == number of ticks since midnight (each tick is 1/300 of a second).
```

This works, but I can't figure out how the above hex number (0xFFFF2E4600000000) translates into 1753-01-01. 2's complement, various transformations on days between 1900 and 1753, etc - nothing works. Search results at Google that it throws at me are not helpful either. Please advise!

*UPDATE*:

It seems like it has smth to do with 2's complement anyway, see the following, but it still not quite works, in Python shell:

```
>>> e=1900-1753
>>> e
147
>>> 
>>> e*=365
>>> e
53655
>>> e=e-(1<<32)
>>> e
-4294913641L
>>> hex(e)
'-0xffff2e69L'
```

That's close to 0xFFFF2E46 but not quite there. What's going on here?

*UPDATE 2:*

Leap days?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me:

```
declare @Sample as DateTime = '1753-01-01'
select @Sample as 'Sample', Cast( @Sample as VarBinary(8) ) as 'VarBinary',
  DateDiff( day, '1900-01-01', @Sample ) as 'DateDiff',
  Cast( DateDiff( day, '1900-01-01', @Sample ) as VarBinary(4) ) as 'Hex DateDiff'
```

Note that the hex value is treated as a signed 32-bit value.

If the question is "Why 53,690?" then the answer is:

```
; with Years as (
  select 1753 as Year, 0 as LeapYear
  union all
  select Year + 1,
    case
     when ( Year + 1 ) % 400 = 0 then 1
     when ( Year + 1 ) % 100 = 0 then 0
     when ( Year + 1 ) % 4 = 0 then 1
     else 0 end
    from Years
    where Year < 1900 )
  select 147 * 365 + Sum( LeapYear ) as Days from Years
  option ( maxrecursion 0 )
```